# Typescript with React: Set type of rendered react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I set a type of rendered React component in Typescript ?
For example: 
I have some React class:

```
const Test: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = (): JSX.Element = (
  <div>some text</div>
);
```

if we console it like:

```
console.log(<Test />)
```

we get a result like:

```
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
  ...
  type: {
    name: 'Test'
  }
}
```

if I want to pass this rendered component as prop and I have such typescript interface:

```
interface Props {
  test: JSX.Element | React.ReactNode
}
```

Can **I specify type of this rendered result** of Test component, like this is an instance of component Test, for example (I know that JSX.Element is not a generic, it's just an abstract example):

```
interface Props {
  test: JSX.Element<Test>
}
```

Comment: You can't do `JSX.Element<anything really>` because `Element` is not generic. But my question is what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: if we have type like JSX.Element we can pass into props anything, I mean any rendered component, but we need strongly special type, like typeof Test. Yes I know that JSX.Element is not generic. It's just for example

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface and use it like this:

```
// This could be JSX.Element or whatever
interface SomeReactComponent {
  A: string;
} 

interface SomeOtherComponent extends SomeReactComponent {
  B: number;
}

const CompA: SomeReactComponent = { A: "123" };
const CompB: SomeOtherComponent = { A: "123", B: 123 };
const anythingElse: number | string | symbol | object = 1;

const someOtherComponent = (input: SomeOtherComponent) => {
  console.log(input);
};

someOtherComponent(CompA); // Won't compile
someOtherComponent(CompB); // OK
someOtherComponent(anythingElse); // Won't compile either
```

So in your case `extend`ing `React.FunctionComponent<{}>` should work.

One minor pitfall: If you're going down this route, you gotta make sure that your interfaces aren't empty or identical. This means simply extending `React.Component` with an empty interface won't work.